# get email receiver language setting python

Tags: python, email

I want to know if it's possible to get the email language setting of a user using python. To be more specific, I'm trying to set up an email notification system that notifies users by email when they receive a message, I don't want to really use their browser language setting because the sender and receiver could have different language setting on their browser. I want to know if it's possible, knowing the receiver's email, to get the language setting of their email?

Comment: Nope, simply because like the browser that is a per-application per-install thing.  Why not simply prompt the user for their preferred language when you get permission to send the notification?

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up doing. thx you.

Comment: Excellent, submitting as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Nope, simply because like the browser that is a per-application per-install thing. Why not simply prompt the user for their preferred language when you get permission to send the notification?